# localStorage Keeps Overwriting My Data

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage, overwrite

I am saving values from my dropdown box into `localStorage`. However, I don't want the data to be overwritten with the new info the next time user choose from the dropdown menu. I just want to keep adding value to my `localStorage` without it overwriting. Any help will be appreciated.

JavaScript code:

```
function reason(){
        var dropd = document.getElementById("savedrop").value;
        var drophistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedrop"));
        localStorage.setItem("reason", JSON.stringify(dropd));
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<select id="savedrop">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please choose one</option>
                    <option value="one">1</option>
                    <option value="two">2</option>
                    <option value="three">3</option>
                </select>
<input id="btnbutton" class="btn" type="button" onClick="reason()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding without overwriting? Is it an array and you want to push new value to it or it is a number and you want to sum the new value to it? Can you try to explain it more clearly?

Comment: it's an array, I just want it to add the value ("one, two or three") into localstorage without overwriting. Like if the user chose "one" in a session, then in another session the user chose "three", I want the data in localstorage to display "[one three]" etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `localStorage` data is saved in key value pairs of strings.
Each time you call `setItem()` it will add or overwrite existing value. And `getItem()` just fetches the value stored in `localStorage` which is a string value. To solve this you have to use an array, `stringify` it and then store it.
Below is the correct code:

```
function reason(){
    var dropd = document.getElementById("savedrop").value;
    var drophistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("reason")) || [];
    drophistory.push(dropd);
    localStorage.setItem("reason", JSON.stringify(drophistory));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the data first, push the new value then overwrite it:

```
function reason(){
        var dropd = document.getElementById("savedrop").value;
        var drophistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedrop"));
        drophistory.push(droph);
        localStorage.setItem("reason", JSON.stringify(drophistory));
    }
```