# How to loop through localStorage values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am creating a React application that you write in a recipe name and ingredients, and they will appear as a list on the page for each recipe created. I was going to use .map to create the list items, but I need an array to work with that and the localStorage is not an array(I believe anyways). Would there be a way to transport each key in the localStorage to an array?

The localStorage, each time you hit the "add recipe" button, adds a key of "recipe name" plus a number for ordering purposes. The value is the recipe itself. I just want to add the recipes to an array as well for .map.

Comment: Post some details, `localStorage` structure and expected array.

Comment: `localStorage` is object, if you store anything inside as array just do `localStorage.yourArray.map`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: Added some more details. I wouldn't say this question is the same as that one. He wanted to store an object in localStorage, while I want to basically store each recipe item into both the storage and an array.

Comment: EDIT: this solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843773/localstorage-keeps-overwriting-my-data

Comment: EDIT: this solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843773/localstorage-keeps-overwriting-my-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `Object.keys(localStorage)`. As you requested a *key*:

```
var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
```

Easy as that! That returns an array of keys. Now, if you want the values:

```
var arrayOfValues = Object.values(localStorage);
```

It returns an array.

Note that `Object.values` is experimental, so an alternative would be:

```
var arrayOfValues = [];
for(var i in localStorage){
    if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        arrayOfValues.push(localStorage[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Simple and effective. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember that `Object.values` is experimental.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `localStorage.length`, it will give the total count of keys present in `localStorage`. Iterate using this length and use `localStorage.key(index)` to get the key name, like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)        
   let key = localStorage.key(i);
   console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer as well.